# Can't create new objects using constructor when declaring empty array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, constructor, p5.js

I'm writing this p5.js code using array of objects, it should be creating a new object generated by Particle() constructor function whenever I press the mouse, and then store it into the array pts[]. However, after pressing the mouse, the code somehow doesn't enter the for loop. I've tried to initialize the array length but the program would be stuck and I have to force quit it...Can anyone help with this situation? Many thanks!

```
var pts = []; 
var onPressed;
//pts.length=2;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(720, 720);
  smooth();
  frameRate(30);
  colorMode(HSB);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  background(255);
}

function draw() {
  //draw new particle when pressed
  if (onPressed) {
    println("checked press");
    for (var i=0;i<=pts.length;i++) {
      println("entered for loop");
      var newP = new Particle(mouseX, mouseY, i+pts.length, i+pts.length);
      //println("newP");
      pts.push(newP);
    }
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  onPressed = true;
  println("presses");
}

function mouseReleased() {
  onPressed = false;
}

function Particle(x, y, xOffset, yOffset){
  println("called Particle");
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
  this.xOffset=xOffset;
  this.yOffset=yOffset;
}
```

Comment: The code in `draw()` looks like it wants to add a new particle for each particle that's already in the list. If there are 0 particles, then zero are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop doesn't make a ton of sense. Your `pts` variable starts out as empty, so when will you ever enter this?

```
for (var i=0;i<=pts.length;i++) {
```

In fact, why are you looping at all? It seems like you just want to add a new `Particle`:

```
  var newP = new Particle(mouseX, mouseY, i+pts.length, i+pts.length);
  pts.push(newP);
```

Also, why are you creating your own `onPressed` variable when you could just use the existing `mouseIsPressed` variable?